# Retrofit + AWS S3 - Presigned URL uploading multiple images, should I use a loop with PUT requests?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, retrofit2

I have a AWS Lambda function that a user makes a `GET request` to and it returns presigned URL. The user then uploads an image by making a PUT request to that URL. Since AWS S3 `PUT requests` limits object uploads to only one per URL,

How would I send multiple images? Am I supposed to use a loop on the current number of images e.g:

Say the user wants to upload 5 images.

```
for(...5 images...){
   Make GET request to generate URL
   In the callback method, 
   Make a PUT request to the generated URL to upload image
}
```

I am not sure if the service is supposed to be used this way. And also this causes another issue, say what if I want all the images to be uploaded and saved into my DB, or none to be saved. Because in the `PUT request's` post process Lambda function, I want to save that S3 image URL into my database, how do I ensure all the images are uploaded and not only 3/5 of them if the network fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. A presigned url is specifically generated to upload a single file.

If you would like to implement such atomic behaviour where all the files uploaded or none uploaded, you will need to implement such logic by your self.

For example , upload all the files to a different S3 location. Then you should have a service or function to move the files to the actual location once all the files are uploaded.

Comment: Just wondering, since it's September already, is there still no way to upload multiple files using presigned url?

Comment: @imin Are you referring to an issue? There's no reason for such a method to suddenly appear.